# How to unpublish older version of APK from Playstore?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have already published many versions of my App in Playstore.

But user can still download an older version of APK.

[image]

You can see currently I have 5 versions of APK in PlayStore.

Version 9, 16, 18, 19 and 45

I have Samsung(Android 4.4.4), MotoG4 (Android 7.0), Lenovo Tab (version 6.0), Moto G (Android 5.1.1), Android Screen (Android 5.1) and many other devices.

When I download App from PlayStore I will get 45 version of APK expect Android Screen (Android 5.1).

**In Android Screen (Android 5.1), I will get 19 version of APK.**

Don't know what is the issue.

Version 9 or 19 is too older i.e 1.5 years older.

**So How can I unpublish old versions of APK?**

Comment: how can users download older version of Apk ?

Comment: I don't know, but When I buy 1 tab from china and install My App from Playstore, and check app version after install, the version code was 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a new release [as described on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011)
- Any APKs you don't want active, then deactivate them
- publish your release

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for unpublish you are not able to unpublish particular version of the application:

Please note that you unpublish (and this means just what name says, nothing more) not just APK - you hide all related stuff (app's page in Google Play etc). To end user it looks like the app is gone. For you - it is still in your console, you can edit description, images, see comments, stats or update APKs etc., but unless you publish it again, nobody will see these changes.

Comment: I don't want to unpublish all the version, only older version need to be unpublish.

Comment: have you tried to unpublish the application and then update the application after that live new update of the application?

Comment: No, I didn't try that way.